# Visualizing custom loss in double-head model

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

Using an A2C agent from [this article](http://inoryy.com/post/tensorflow2-deep-reinforcement-learning/), how to get numerical values of `value_loss`, `policy_loss` and `entropy_loss` when weights are being updated?

The model I'm using is double-headed, both heads share the same trunk. The policy head output shape is `[number of actions, batch size]` and value head has a shape of `[1, batch_size]`. Compiling this model returns a size incompatibility error, when these loss functions are given as metrics:

```
self.model.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, 
                   metrics=[self._logits_loss, self._value_loss], 
                   loss=[self._logits_loss, self._value_loss])
```

Both `self._value_loss` and `self._policy_loss` are executed as graphs, meaning that all variables inside them are only pointers to graph nodes. I found some examples where Tensor objects are evaluated (with eval()) to get the value out of nodes. I don't understand them because in order to eval() a Tensor object you need to give it a Session but in TensorFlow 2.x Sessions are deprecated.

Another lead, when calling `train_on_batch()` from [Model API](https://keras.io/models/model/) in Keras to train the model, the method returns losses. I don't understand why, but the only losses it returns are from the policy head. Losses from that head are calculated as `policy_loss - entropy_loss` but my goal is to get all three losses separately to visualize them in a graph.

Any help is welcome, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. In Keras, the `metrics` built-in functionality provides an interface for measuring performance and losses of the model, be it a custom or standard one.

When compiling a model as follows:

```
self.model.compile(optimizer=ko.RMSprop(lr=lr),
                   metrics=dict(output_1=self._entropy_loss),
                   loss=dict(output_1=self._logits_loss, output_2=self._value_loss))
```

... `self.model.train_on_batch([...])` returns a list of `[total_loss, logits_loss, value_loss, entropy_loss]`. By making a calculation of `logits_loss + entropy_loss` the value of `policy_loss` can be calculated. Beware, that this solution results in calling `self._entropy_loss()` twice.